# Setting maxDate in Material UI DatePicker Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been struggling to get the `maxDate` prop on the Material UI `DatePicker` component to work as expected. That is, dates after the `maxDate` are disabled.

My use case required setting the `maxDate` to `+60 days` from the current `Date()` with dates thereafter disabled.

Please see my answer for a solution that is working on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working solution via `CodeSandbox` found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datepicker-maxdate-d2m24z?file=/src/App.jsx).

If you prefer the code instead of `CodeSandbox`:

`index.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import "./App.css";

render(
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <App />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

`App.jsx`

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import moment from "moment";
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function App() {
  const dayjs = require("dayjs");
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  // function for setting the maxDate for DatePicker
  // return value is current date + X days
  const setMaxDate = (daysToAdd) => {
    const now = new Date();
    const nowPlusDays = now.setDate(now.getDate() + daysToAdd);
    return moment(dayjs(nowPlusDays).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        maxDate={setMaxDate(60)}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```